# Python Anywhere - User uploaded files not working - css / banners etc. working fine

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, pythonanywhere

I have followed the tutorial on static files on [PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/) but I can't access the images and

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

returns the following error:

"**ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem
path.**"

My development settings file looks like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/Dude1983/surfapp/static'
```

and I've also tried this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Everything else works fine and the css files and background images work, but user uploaded files don't...

I've been googling and reading the Django documentation. Any pointers what I'm doing wrong here?

My Git repository can be found [here](https://github.com/Dude1983/surfapp).

Comment: Check both `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`. In the event that they're pointing to the same location, that's your problem.

You could try removing `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: Checked that, but sadly nothing changed.

Comment: What's in your STATICFILES_FINDERS? Also is your STATIC_ROOT  defined before STATICFILES_FINDERS?

Comment: Until now the project didn't have a STATICFILES_FINDERS.

Comment: Any chance it's a Django version issue?  It looks like you're using a virtualenv from the git repo's README -- are you running the collectstatic command from a bash prompt that's inside the virtualenv?

Comment: Yes Giles, I'm running the collect static from a bash prompt within the virtualenv which is Python 3.4.

Comment: Okay, I managed to run collectstatic, but the images are not available under www.projectname.com/media but when I change it to www.projectname.com/static the picture appears.  Not sure what's wrong...Feel like I'm completely stupid.